# Transmit changing shunt resistor voltage value using analog optocoupler

Tags: operational-amplifier, opto-isolator

I would like to use the IL300 to transmit the voltage of a shunt-resistor. The voltage value of the shunt changes between 0 up to 1 volt in 1ms depending on the load. On the receiving side of the optocoupler I want roughly the same voltage values of the shunt to further use an INA226 to measure to current.
Do I need a "op amp voltage current driver" and rail to rail op amp to achive this? If so, what would be a fitting rail to rail op amp that can use the shunt resistor voltages?

Is this the circuit I have to use?

[image]

Comment: Conceptually this is a valid solution but I would suggest there are most likely simpler, cheaper and more accurate methods to achieve the same result. First that comes to mind is hall effect. Downside is usually the noise floor limits resolution. If the measurement is AC, then a current transformer. Other thoughts are voltage to frequency or even a tiny single chip micro to convert the analog to digital and send it via transformer, opto or integrated isolation devices from the likes of Analog Devices.